# IIS 7 - Application pools

Tags: iis, iis-7, application-pools

I made a CompanySite website in IIS - it's the only website on that server.

I created .NET 4 Integrated pool for that website.

I've installed ASP.Net site into CompanySite and it works fine.

Now I'd like to install an application within this site. I create another .NET 4 application pool for that application. Then I install application into CompanySite using that application pool.

As soon as setup starts off the website goes offline either with 503 or with The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

The only way to fix this (that I have found) is to uninstall that application and restart Windows Server, not just IIS server.

Question is how can I install multiple applications within a single site?

THank you

Comment: What does your system event log say?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did it right. You have to create two application pools, set the right .NET framework and associate the app pool in "Advanced Settings" of the "sub folder" application.

There could be a problem because of nested web.config files. Try to put the physical folder of your second application *outside* the physical folder of the main site.

Example:

```
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mainsite
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\subsite
```

and create a virtual directory application.

Also, check the Application Event log in Event Viewer. Perhaps there are some other error message which could help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the app targeted for .net 4?  Each app pool needs to be set to the appropriate .net version for the apps it contains.  So you can't mix different .net versions in the same app pool.  Also when you change the version you will probably need to iisreset.